# Error when I am trying to run: git push heroku master

Tags: heroku, node.js

I am trying to push my nodejs project to my Heroku app. The code can be found here: https://github.com/birgirp/thehole.

The error I get is the following:

```
$ git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 494, done.
Counting objects: 100% (494/494), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (220/220), done.
Writing objects: 100% (494/494), 6.10 MiB | 538.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 494 (delta 231), reused 485 (delta 227)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
remote:                         HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
remote:                         See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to thehole.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/thehole.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/thehole.git'
```

Any ideas what might be causing the error?

Thanks, Birgir

Comment: PS. I just created the heroku app using "heroku create thehole". So this is the first attempt to push the code to heroku.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have not checked out master first.

In order to resolve this you would have to make sure you are on the same branch and your local repo is up to date.

I would

1. git checkout master
2. git pull
3. git push origin master

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I cloned my github repo from master so that seems not to be the problem:
   $ git checkout master
   Already on 'master'
   Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Comment: can you post a copy of your package.json file? you might not have the node / dependency verisons in it

Comment: There are two package.json files, on for the web client (https://github.com/birgirp/thehole/blob/master/client/package.json) and one for the server backend: (https://github.com/birgirp/thehole/blob/master/server/package.json)

Comment: This is the issue.... heroku requires the package.json file to be in the root folder... not sure how you would bypass that as there are 2 package.json files

Comment: ah ok thanks! I'll try to resolve that...

Comment: Resolved by refactoring and having package.json at the root.